# Trying to get raw image url for a Facebook graph request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to store the raw url for a FB image in my DB (the url that is redirected to from a Facebook image graph request).  I am trying to do this in PHP.  I am trying to use:

```
$raw_picture = json_decode('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$somefbid.'/picture?width=720&height=720', true);
        $data['picture'] = $raw_picture['url'];
        dd($data['picture']);
```

The dd line returns NULL.

Do you know how I get the raw url from this type of request?  Thank you.

Comment: What is `var_dump($raw_picture);`?

Comment: Check that you're getting a working result from $raw_picture.

Comment: You shouldn't store the raw url. It may stop working at any second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the additional parameter redirect=0 like this:

```
GET /me/picture?redirect=0
```

the output is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "{url}", 
    "is_silhouette": false
  }
}
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/picture/ for reference.